# expand function as power series of another function

Tags: series-expansion

Suppose I have a well-known function $f(x)$ and I want to know if this function can be expanded into power series of another function $g(x)$, like $f(x)=\sum_n a_n g^n(x)$, where $a_n$ is the coefficient of $n$-th power of $g(x)$. How should I do this using Mathematica?

Comment: How about `f[x_] = Sin[x]; g[x_] = 3 + x^(1/2); sol = First@Solve[g[x] == y, x] ` yiels  `{x -> 9 - 6 y + y^2} `  and `Series[f[x /. sol], {y, 0, 2}] ` yields `SeriesData[y, 0, {
Sin[9], (-6) Cos[9], Cos[9] - 18 Sin[9]}, 0, 3, 1] ` .

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works!

Comment: For searching purposes: what is being sought here is sometimes referred to as a [Bürmann series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BuermannsTheorem.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following

```
Series[f[InverseFunction[g][y]],{y,0,10}]
```